# $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R^2 $ or $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2 $ for this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Say I have the function $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$ and I want to use vector notation.

**Q1:**

I set $\mathbf x=x_1\hat e_1+x_2\hat e_2=(x_1,x_2)$, so $f(x_1,x_2)=f(\mathbf x)$ and I now have $f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2$.
I guess this is correct?

**Q2**

But should I write
$$
f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2, \quad x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R^2 \quad \tag 1
$$ 
or 
$$
f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2, \quad (x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2 \quad \tag 2
$$

Comment: The second one is right. For the first you could say "$\in \mathbb{R}$".

Comment: Unlike in Python, in maths we strictly require enclosing tuples between a pair of parenthesis :)

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have the function $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$ and I want to use vector
>   notation.
>
> **Q1:**
>
> I set $\mathbf x=x_1\hat e_1+x_2\hat e_2=(x_1,x_2)$, so
>   $f(x_1,x_2)=f(\mathbf x)$ and I now have $f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2$. I
>   guess this is correct?

People often slide between these two forms. Typical is to write
$$
f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R : \mathbf x= (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 + x_2
$$
or 
$$
f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R : (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 + x_2.
$$

One slight challenge is that not everyone writes vectors as list of numbers, i.e. $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$; some folks use column vectors. Then the "pun" between $\mathbf x$ and $(x_1, x_2)$ becomes less clear.

> **Q2**
>
> But should I write $$ f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2, \quad x_1,x_2\in \mathbb
>  R^2 \quad \tag 1 $$  or  $$ f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2, \quad (x_1,x_2)\in
>  \mathbb R^2 \quad \tag 2 $$

For this, I'd be inclined to write

$$ f(\mathbf x)=x_1+x_2, \quad \mathbf x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb
R^2 \quad \tag 1 $$.

None of these is really satisfactory, for you really should commit to $f$ being a function of one argument (a vector) or two arguments ( a pair of real numbers). The right way to write the thing, in this first case, would be 
$$
f( (x_1, x_2) ) = x_1 + x_2
$$
which looks rather better with column vectors:
$$
f( \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} ) = x_1 + x_2.
$$

Be people are generally sloppy, and I don't think I've ever seen anyone (except a programmer who had to write code!) use anything like the first of those two. The second is relatively common, although sometimes the parentheses get dropped, alas.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your point gets across with no confusion, any notation is just fine.

For example, technically speaking, for $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, we *should*, following strict notation, be writing $f((x_1,x_2))$, but we commonly shorten that to $f(x_1,x_2)$.

---

That said, I would say you can either write

> $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2$

because that means that the *tuple* $(x_1,x_2)$ is an element of $\mathbb R^2$ (and, implicitly, that the two elements of the tuple are elements of $\mathbb R$)

**or** you could write

> $x_1, x_2\in \mathbb R$

as that means "both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are elements of $\mathbb R$ (and, therefore, the tuple $(x_1,x_2)$ is an element of $\mathbb R^2$).

---

I would say that $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R^2$ is awkward notation that is not standard for what you are trying to say and can therefore introduce confusion.